# Any tool for database testing (TDD) for Eclipse?

Tags: java, mysql, database, eclipse, tdd

I need to implement simple program that import data from XML file into MySQL database.

The thing is that I have to use TDD (Test Driven Development) during implementation, e.g. I have to write tests before I write code.

I need to test the insertion of data into db, connection, etc.

The db is **MySQL** db.

Which is the best TDD tool for Eclipse for db testing?

Comment: Eclipse? Use maven, jpa and in memory database such as H2?

Comment: I need to use MySQL db.
And testing tool as Fitnesse or something else

Comment: You can emulate MySQL with in-memory databases. Any reason why you wouldn't be using standard (j)unit tests?

Comment: How can I do that? Could you give any example or just an idea of any simple test case? As if I could test an insertion of one record into db

Comment: It may be worth having a look at [DbUnit](http://dbunit.sourceforge.net/) too. It can be very useful for populating an empty database with known data for query testing.

Comment: Unfortunately I do not have any source codes available at home. But I think this might help you a bit: https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/h2-database/o2LPisGJriw

Comment: What are you trying to test? That data is actually inserted into MySQL? If so, use the junit and jdbc mysql driver to write integration tests to make sure the basic functionality works as expected. After that you wrap the jdbc code with your own database class which provides the necessary interfaces. You can write another set of integration tests for this, but it is not required. Once you have that ready extract an interface and create a mock class that you use for your unit testing efforts.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have a good example of TDD with database at [Koskela's book](http://www.manning.com/koskela/).

You can use memory database, as some comments advise you, or mysql database (slower) for your tests.

The important things is that the tests have to leave the testing database exactly as they found it. This makes the tests independent of each other.